# how can I replace div class text inside div id?

Tags: jquery, class, html, replace

I have the following div in my squarespace website:

```
<div id="text-yui_3_10_1_1_1397493196442_28869" class="form-item field text required error">
<div class="field-error">Subject is required.</div>

<div id="number-yui_3_10_1_1_1397494940010_32253" class="form-item field number required error">
<div class="field-error">Phone is required.</div>
```

I would like to change the text of the "field-error" with jquery ("Subject is required" / "Phone is required")

EDIT: sorry, it seems all the code above is only visible when a "submit" button is pressed.

The code for the button is as follows:

```
<input class="button sqs-system-button sqs-editable-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Is it necessary for the replace code to be linked with the button action?

edit2: ok, I found the form code for the submit button:

```
<form onsubmit="return (function(form) { Y.use ('squarespace-form-submit', 'node', function (Y) { (new Y.Squarespace.FormSubmit({ formNode: Y.Node(form) })).submit('534c11ade4b0c1a4ea57934b', '53488d92e4b0f26be11d5d68') }); return false;})(this)" method="POST" action="website_link" autocomplete="on">
```

thanks!

Comment: Show us the actual code you've tried, not a generalized example.

Comment: Maybe it's not working because there are no paragraphs nor are there any elements with the ID #example ?

Comment: I added the actual code!

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess what you mean exactly, but I think this is a pretty good guess considering the DOM you showed. I imagine you are trying to change multiple texts and they are getting combined because you are getting the text of `.field-error` which includes multiple elements. You'll have to do them individually, try something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkML3/)

```
$(".field-error").each( function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace("required", "optional"));
});
```

This will go through each match on the selector (.field-error) and replace them individually. If you did something like `$(".field-error").text($(".field-error").text().replace("required", "optional"));` you would end up with merged texts as each `.field-error` would contain the text within all `.field-error`.

---

Seeing your update, it looks like your DOM is wrong as well. Try this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkML3/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="text-yui_3_10_1_1_1397493196442_28869" class="form-item field text required error">
<div class="field-error">Subject is required.</div>
</div>

<div id="number-yui_3_10_1_1_1397494940010_32253" class="form-item field number required error">
<div class="field-error">Phone is required.</div>
</div>
```

CODE:

```
$fe = $("#text-yui_3_10_1_1_1397493196442_28869 .field-error");
$fe.text($fe.text().replace("Subject is required.", "test"));
```

---

With the latest info... try this:

```
function replacementSubmitFunction() {
    return (function (form) {
        Y.use('squarespace-form-submit', 'node', function (Y) {
            (new Y.Squarespace.FormSubmit({
                formNode: Y.Node(form)
            })).submit('534c11ade4b0c1a4ea57934b', '53488d92e4b0f26be11d5d68')
        });
        $(".field-error").each(function () {
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace("required", "optional"));
        });
        return false;
    })(this)
}
$("form").get(0).onsubmit = replacementSubmitFunction;
```

Comment: thanks for helping. I edited it again, I realized now that there is a submit button and it is only when it's pressed that the div code is visible. Does the replace code need to be linked to the button?

Comment: Almost there, I guess. Calling the function after on submit works; but the $fe replace code doesn't. Any alternative codes?

Maybe the code needs to be run after the submit button? I'm thinking that because the field-errors are only visible after I click the button

Comment: @user3507859 It's hard to tell without seeing the full thing. When you click the button I'm guessing a form is getting submitted and the page is refreshed?

Comment: edit: the page doesn't reload.
I don't understand why it's not working. I copied the exact same code in  the fiddle and it won't work.

Comment: Does your HTML match as well? Are you getting any errors in your js console?

Comment: The funny thing is that I added a "alert('working')" on submit and it shows the alert. however, it doesn't replace the words

Comment: When the alert shows up, are the field-errors present already? Or not until after the alert?

Comment: I put two alerts, one before the replace code and one after it. 
Both show up before the field-errors appear. 
My guess is that the replace code is not working because it's run before the field-errors codes are visible! 
Is there a way to call the code after the submit? Instead of "on submit"

Comment: Well the thing is that the submit is never happening, it's getting stopped... otherwise the form's action page would load. There must be another javascript which is built in to whatever framework you are using that is also preventing the form from submitting if the validation is incorrect.

Comment: I found the code for the form submit. Does it help? It looks like there a reference for when the form is incorrectly filled in

Comment: Hard to tell, but this might work... try putting your replace code in a function... like `replaceFieldError()` and then call it just before the `return false();` like `...d68') });replaceFieldError(); return false;})(this)...`

Comment: BTW, this really seems like something you should be doing on the back end or with the framework so that it comes up with the validation messages you want rather than changing with javascript after it comes up.

Comment: Yeah I know but there is no option, the form is the way it is, and I need to change some words on it.
The function sounds like a good idea but I can't edit the OnSubmit code unless I use another replace function to add the "replaceFiedlError()" function before the "return false". Is this possible?

Comment: I found out that the thing I'm trying to edit is a textnode.
I have the id (yui_3_10_1_1_1397859382468_1224) and it says it has the value of "Subject is required."
Is there a way of replacing directly the textnode?

Comment: `.text()` will get all the text from the textnodes within that element. You could replace the onsubmit function like this: `$('form').get(0).onsubmit = myfunction` ... then have "myfunction" be the existing function but also add the text replace before the return false.